# tar.unpack error installing a script package on Atom

Tags: node.js, npm, atom-editor

I am trying to install script package on Atom but it gives the following error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack error reading /tmp/d-116420-6290-1xjcgjb/package.tgz
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/d-116420-6290-1xjcgjb/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/nobodyu/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/nobodyu/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-116420-6290-1xjcgjb/package.tgz" "--target=0.36.8" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3

npm ERR! 0-byte tarball
npm ERR! Please run `npm cache clean`
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-116420-6290-1gbk138/npm-debug.log
```

I've also run

```
npm cache clean
```

And

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

But it is still giving me the same error

How can I successfully install this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11798 check here if you are searching for Solution.